# Can I have a polymorphic function argument that may not need to be supplied for some types?

Tags: haskell

I have a datatype `F` with a special-case for `Int`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, RankNTypes #-}
data F a where
   FGen :: a -> F a
   FInt :: F Int
```

Without exposing the details of this datatype to callers - the real datatype is more complicated containing internal implementation details - I want to provide an API for using it:

```
transform :: (a -> b) -> b -> F a -> b
transform f i (FGen v) = f v
transform f i FInt = i
```

If I'm going to call `transform` on a `F Int`, clearly both of the first two arguments are important:

```
transformInt :: F Int -> Int
transformInt = transform (+1) 5
```

But if I'm going to call it on a `F Char`, the second argument is unnecessary as the value can't be a `FInt`:

```
transformChar :: F Char -> Char
transformChar = transform id (error "unreachable code")
```

Is there a way I can express this in the type of `transform`?

I tried

```
transform :: (a -> b) -> (a ~ Int => b) -> F a -> b
transform f i (FGen v) = f v
transform f i FInt = i
```

but then `transformChar` doesn't compile with

```
    Couldn't match type ‘Char’ with ‘Int’
    Inaccessible code in
      a type expected by the context: (Char ~ Int) => Char
    In the second argument of ‘transform’, namely
      ‘(error "unreachable code")’
    In the expression: transform id (error "unreachable code")
    In an equation for ‘transformChar’:
        transformChar = transform id (error "unreachable code")
```

and anyway I'd still want `absurd` value I could use instead of the error to  properly express that the compiler should be able to prove the code will never be used.

Comment: Have you tried a closed type family that's unit/void/something absurd for every non-`Int` type?

Comment: Generally speaking, you could do even more: `> :t FGen (2 :: Int) ;
FGen (2 :: Int) :: F Int`

Comment: GHC handling of unsatisfiable contexts is rather peculiar in cases like this. One would expect it to follow "ex falso quod libet".

Comment: @Cirdec - interesting idea, what would I do with the type family?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use the propositional equality type in [`Data.Type.Equality`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/base-4.8.1.0/Data-Type-Equality.html) and we can also express inaccessibility of code from GHC 7.8, using empty case expressions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, RankNTypes, EmptyCase, TypeOperators #-}

import Data.Type.Equality   

data F a where
   FGen :: a -> F a
   FInt :: F Int

transform :: (a -> b) -> ((a :~: Int) -> b) -> F a -> b
transform f i (FGen v) = f v
transform f i FInt = i Refl

transformChar :: F Char -> Char
transformChar = transform id (\p -> case p of {})
-- or (\case {}) with LambdaCase

transformInt :: F Int -> Int
transformInt = transform (+1) (const 5)
```

Comment: Nice. This a case where I really wish GHC exhaustiveness checker was better: it correctly generates no warning for the empty case (good!), but it also does the same if I move to `F Int -> Int` (bad!). (GHC 7.8 here -- I don't know whether GHC 7.10 fixed this)

Comment: Thanks! The key points as I see them are to turn the impossible class context into an impossible value with the `:~:` GADT (the one in the library isn't special though normally it's the most logical one to use - I could define my own if I want) and also to use empty case expressions to implement `absurd`.

Answer (score 4):

I like the answer with a [GADT for the type equality proof](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31872038/414413) better. This answer explains how to do the same thing with `TypeFamilies`. With closed type families we can write functions from types to the unit `()` and zero `Void` of the type system to represent prepositional truth and false.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import Data.Void

type family IsInt a where
    IsInt Int = ()
    IsInt a   = Void
```

The second argument to `transform` is `() -> b` when `IsInt a` and `Void -> b` (the type of `absurd`) when `a` isn't an integer.

```
transform :: (a -> b) -> (IsInt a -> b) -> F a -> b
transform f i (FGen v) = f v
transform f i FInt = i ()
```

`transformChar` can be written in terms of `absurd` and `transformInt` must pass in `b` as a constant function.

```
transformChar :: F Char -> Char
transformChar = transform id absurd

transformInt :: F Int -> Int
transformInt = transform (+1) (const 5)
```

#### More Reusable

At [András Kovács](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1068232/andr%c3%a1s-kov%c3%a1cs) suggestion, we can make this more reusable with a type family for type equality `(==)` that returns lifted `Bool`s.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}

type family (==) a b :: Bool where
    (==) a a = True
    (==) a b = False
```

We could provide another type family to convert `True` to `()` and `False` to `Void`. For this specific problem it reads better to go all the way from `True` or `False` and some type `b` to `() -> b` or `Void -> b`.

```
type family When p b where
    When True  b = ()   -> b
    When False b = Void -> b
```

The type of `transform` then reads.

```
transform :: (a -> b) -> When (a == Int) b -> F a -> b
```

Comment: Tip: this would be more reusable with a distinct `(==)` type family that returns lifted `Bool`-s and an `IsTrue b` type family that converts the lifted bools into `()` or `Void`.